# Template function overloading (generic type vs template template type) choose correct overload

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I have a template function which does something with a given value as long as the template type is a number:

```
template <typename scalar_t>
void function(scalar_t value)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_floating_point_v<scalar_t>)
    {
        std::cout << value << 'F';
    }
    if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<scalar_t>)
    {
        std::cout << value;
    }
}
```

And an overload for this template expecting a container containing numbers:

```
template <typename scalar_t, template <typename> class container_t>
void function(const container_t<scalar_t> &container)
{
    for (const auto &value : container)
    {
        function(value);
        std::cout << ' ';
    }
}
```

With the templates above, I call the following code:

```
int main()
{
    function('0');
    function(short{1});
    function(2);
    function(3l);
    function(4ll);
    function(5.f);
    function(6.);

    std::vector<int> v{7, 8, 9, 10};
    std::list<double> l{11., 12., 13., 14.};

    function(v);
    function(l);

    return 0;
}
```

Which gives the following output:

```
012345F6F
```

While I was expecting the following output:

```
012345F6F7 8 9 10 11F 12F 13F 14F
```

Which means that the first template version (`function(scalar_t value)`) has been chosen instead of the second version (`function(const container_t<scalar_t> &container)`).

How can I force the second version of the template-function to be chosen for template template parameters?

Comment: not sure if thats the problem, but both `vector` and `list` dont have one but two template parameters

Comment: @tobi303 [that was the problem indeed](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kvKHSpDJ6VEOWhRO) if you can explain why in an answer I can upvote it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that your template types do not match.  `std::vector` and `std::list` both have a template parameter for the allocator.  `template <typename> class container_t` does not allow that so the template does not match so `void function(scalar_t value)` is called and nothing happens.

What you need to do is take a variadic template template parameter.  Using

```
template <typename scalar_t, template <typename...> class container_t>
void function(const container_t<scalar_t> &container)
{
    for (const auto &value : container)
    {
        function(value);
        std::cout << ' ';
    }
}
```

You get

```
012345F6F7 8 9 10 11F 12F 13F 14F
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SxR84lfU4yk3X6hv)</kbd>

Comment: Interestingly, `gcc` and `clang` work differently with this code. Is `clang` correct?

Comment: @EdgarRokyan That is interesting.  AFAIK, clang is behaving correctly here.  I'm not sure why gcc accepts it.

Comment: @EdgarRokyan Looks like something changed in gcc between C++14 and 17.  [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e814e634d60dfeaf) fails to compile in C++14 mode but compiles in C++17 mode.  Now I'm not sure if something happened in C++17 to allow it or if it is bug in gcc's c++17 implementation.

Comment: I see... Unfortunately, I'm not a templates expert, so I don't know whether this behaviour is correct or not...

Comment: This was retroactively changed in [DR 150](http://wg21.link/p0522); the old behavior is that templates must match exactly, while the new behavior (retroactively applied to C++14) is that you can skip template parameters with default arguments.\

Comment: @DanielH Cool.  Did not know that changed.  That should make life easier going forward.

Comment: I am actually seeing contradictions about how retroactive the change is meant to be, possibly for weird bureaucratic reasons or the ISO standards process not quite being intended for programming languages and them not quite fitting the model precisely. I guess the only relevant definition is [GCC’s `-fnew-ttp-matching` flag](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#index-fnew-ttp-matching), which is only enabled by default in C++17 mode.

Comment: @DanielH Looks like it is still an open issue.  Maybe it looks like it will be accepted so gcc decided to implement it already while clang is holding off.

Comment: It’s [listed as DR](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#150) in the CWG issue list, but based on [the definitions](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#Issue%20Status) it looks like it should be DRWP, since it is C++17 DIS. The top of the page basically implies that doesn’t mean anything yet, but even though cppreference is non-authoritative I expect they know more than I do on the subject and they say [it was retroactively changed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Defect_reports).